# converting a UITextField tag to a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

this gives me an error, "Bad Reciever type 'NSIntegar" (aka 'int').

```
    NSString *tempTag = [((UITextField *)[self.dataSetDictionary objectForKey:key]).tag stringValue];
```

trying to typecast a uitextfield's tag to an string. i can use [NSString stringWithFormat] fine, just can't figure out why this way won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tag` is a property of UIView object of NSInteger data type. You cannot pass messages to it. `stringValue` should be called on `NSNumber`. What you should be doing is

```
NSString *tempTag=(NSString*)[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[(UITextField*)[self.dataSetDictionary objectForKey:key] tag]] stringValue];
```

Comment: @Log139 Whoops, made a mistake on the ']'. Try the edited one

Comment: ha, yep, that did it. i couldn't figure out where the missing [] were, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `stringWithFormat:`

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.dataSetDictionary objectForKey:key];
NSString *tempTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", textField.tag];
```

> just can't figure out why this way won't work.

Because `tag` is a scalar integer and not an object. You can't send messages like `stringValue` to non-objects.

Comment: yep, this way does work. i was just trying to figure out why the other way wasn't working when it seemed like it should have.

Answer (score -3):

NSIntegers are not objects

[more info](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsnumber-and-nsinteger.html)